# Migrated question loses points

Tags: discussion

Recently, I answered a question that earn some points.  The question was then migrated to [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/50807/why-do-boys-sweat-more-than-girls-during-exercise) and I lost those points.  I'm trying to understand the logic behind this.  Can anyone explain the loss of points?

Answer (score 1):

You would also lose (or gain) points when with associated answers is deleted, things like that. Points accrue to and follow the question. If the question moves to another site, then all answers and points associated with both move with it. This is so that you don't gain points for a question or answer on two different sites.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to associate your account with the Biology site, your reputation there would accrue the transferred points.

It is the same principal as how reputation gained for edits/answers [disappears](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) if the underlying question gets deleted (in most circumstances, see [here for exceptions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/))

Comment: Is that spelled out anywhere in the help documentation?

Comment: Not in the help documentation per se, but I did see a similar situation discussed in meta.stackoverflow by Shog9 when I researched this answer.  Afraid I cannot find it again.